# Javascript/ES6: Insert Group-By-element in JSON object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuetify.js

I receive a JSON-object from an API like thhis:

```
       {
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorieId": 1,
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorie": "Miete",
    "Group": "Ideeller Bereich"
    },
      {
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorieId": 2,
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorie": "Taiko-Beitrag",
    "Group": "Ideeller Bereich"
    },
   {
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorieId": 5,
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorie": "Jahresbeitrag",
    "Group": "Ideeller Bereich"
},
      {
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorieId": 3,
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorie": "Reisekosten (Auftritt)",
    "Group": "Zweckbetrieb"
    },
      {
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorieId": 4,
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorie": "Auftritt",
    "Group": "Zweckbetrieb"
    },
```

Now when using a Vuetify selection there's an option to group by some header. Thus I would like to transform my result like this:

```
    {header: "Ideller Bereich" },  
    {
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorieId": 1,
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorie": "Miete",
    "Group": "Ideeller Bereich"
    },
      {
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorieId": 2,
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorie": "Monatsbeitrag",
    "Group": "Ideeller Bereich"
    },
  {
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorieId": 5,
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorie": "Jahresbeitrag",
    "Group": "Ideeller Bereich"
  },
  {header: Zweckbetrieb },
      {
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorieId": 3,
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorie": "Reisekosten",
    "Group": "Zweckbetrieb"
    },
      {
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorieId": 4,
    "BuchungsvorgangKategorie": "Auftritt",
    "Group": "Zweckbetrieb"
    }
```

I suppose I should cycle (arr.map?) through the array of objects and have a check-variable which is initially empty. Always if the current value of Group is different from the check-variable I need to update the check variable and insert the new value on the position before the current item (arr.splice?)

**Update:**

Thanks to the comments by @trincot and @Natixco which helped me into investigating further I was able to create this little piece of code:

```
 let checkVariable = ""
this.FilterKategorien.forEach((item,index) => { //this.FilterKategorien contained the records from the API.
            if(item.Group!=checkVariable) {
              this.FilterKategorien.splice(index,0,{header: item.Group})
              checkVariable=item.Group
            }
          })
          console.log(this.FilterKategorien)
```

Comment: That is not valid JSON. You probably speak of an array...?

Comment: Exactly, but I'd use foreach if you don't need a new array.

Comment: Well, your supposition in the last paragraph has the right idea. Did you try it out?

Comment: Yes, i did now... Thank you for the nudge into the right direction:
let checkVariable = ""
this.FilterKategorien.forEach((item,index) => {
            if(item.BuchungsvorgangSteuerzuordnung!=checkVariable) {
              this.FilterKategorien.splice(index,0,{header: item.BuchungsvorgangSteuerzuordnung})
              checkVariable=item.BuchungsvorgangSteuerzuordnung
            }
          })
          console.log(this.FilterKategorien)

Comment: So you need to *modify* the array; not create a new one?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to modify the result. I suppose it works now; I don't know, whether or not it's elegant though...

Comment: You *suppose* it works? Did you try with more than 2 groups?

Comment: Ah, yes, it also works with three groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a new array; you can always assign it back to the original variable:

```
let grouped = data.reduce((acc, item, i) =>
    !i || acc[acc.length-1].Group !== item.Group 
        ? acc.concat({header: item.Group}, item)
        : acc.concat(item)
, []);
```

If you really need to mutate the original array, you can also use the above, and splice it into the original:

```
data.splice(0, data.length, ...data.reduce((acc, item, i) =>
    !i || acc[acc.length-1].Group !== item.Group 
        ? acc.concat({header: item.Group}, item)
        : acc.concat(item)
, []));
```

Comment: Thank you tincot. It's interesting to see the very different approach. Thank you for introducing concat which I have never used before :-)

Comment: I was thinking about this solution regarding this snippet:  !i || acc[acc.length-1].Group !== item.Group 
!i means: if there's no i then do something. Why do I need this?`During the first iteration, i equals 0, right? So it's already different from undefined....

Comment: `!i` is false when `i` is 0. `!i` coerces `i` to a boolean, so it becomes either false or true.